# how to use correctly bcrypt php class

Tags: php, hash, authentication, passwords, bcrypt

i'm trying to use bcrypt class but not working when i want to use the verify code. It always hash a new password, so i can't login.

```
 <?php
        $password = Bcrypt::hashPassword($_POST['mdp_user']);

        $pwdVerify = Bcrypt::checkPassword($_POST['mdp_user'], $password); 

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tgn_users WHERE login="' . $_POST[ 'login' ] . '" AND mdp_user="' . $password  . '"';

        echo $sql;

        $req = mysqli_query( $connexion, $sql )or die( mysqli_error( $connexion ) );

        if ( mysqli_num_rows( $req ) > 0 ) {
                $nom_user = $_SESSION['nom_user'];
                $prenom_user = $_SESSION['prenom_user'];
                $_SESSION[ 'islog' ] = "connect";
                //header( 'Location: ../../profile.php' );
        } else {
                $_SESSION[ 'login' ] = $_POST[ 'login' ];
                $_SESSION[ 'mdp_user' ] = $_POST[ 'mdp_user' ];
                $_SESSION[ 'message' ] = "Erreur de log et/ou de pwd";
                //header( "Location: " . $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_REFERER' ] );
        }
  ?>
```

This is the officiel doc. I'am new on bcrypt, i really don't understand how to find a solution. Please help !

```
 <?php
      require_once 'Bcrypt.php';

      // hash the password => returns hashed password
      Bcrypt::hashPassword($password);

      // check $password against the $hashedPassword => returns true/false
      Bcrypt::checkPassword($password, $hashedPassword);
?>
```

Comment: PHP already comes with a `password_*` API, check the [docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php)

Comment: you need to verify against the row, not the hash.

Comment: If you are using a version older than 5.5.0 (which you shouldn't be using), you can use [this library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/) made by Anthony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Magnus Eriksson, i did it and it works.

```
 <?php
 function logUser() {

require( './connexion.php' );

$sql_user = 'SELECT * FROM tgn_users WHERE login="' . $_POST[ 'login' ] . '"';

$req = mysqli_query( $connexion, $sql_user )or die( mysqli_error( $connexion ) );

if ( mysqli_num_rows( $req ) > 0 ) {

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $req );

    if ( Bcrypt::checkPassword( $_POST[ 'mdp_user' ], $row[ 'mdp_user' ] ) ) {

        if($row['login']='admin'){

            header( 'Location: ../../admin/' );

        }else{

            $_SESSION[ 'nom_user' ] = $row[ 'nom_user' ];
            $_SESSION[ 'prenom_user' ] = $row[ 'prenom_user' ];
            $_SESSION[ 'id_user' ] = $row[ 'id_user' ];
            //$lifetime = 60*60*24*30;
            //setcookie(session_name($_SESSION['nom_user']), session_id($_SESSION['id_user']),time()+$lifetime,'/');
            header( 'Location: ../../profile.php' );
        }

    }else {
        $_SESSION[ 'message' ] = "Erreur de log et/ou de pwd";
        header( "Location: " . $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_REFERER' ] );

    }
}

  }?>
```

But i have a problem in my condition. Whatever login is put i'am redirected to the admin page :(. AM I missing something in my if condition ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `password_hash` and `password_verify` for passwords. It supports many hash algorithms, even Bcrypt, and is much easier to understand.
You can select algorithm and rounds (and some more, but don't use it unless you know what you are doing) for `password_hash` and `password_verify` discovers the used algo

- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: _Note:_ Selecting the salt for password_hash() was deprecated in PHP 7.0. (Not my down vote, btw.)

Comment: i did it but when i want to compare the password's storing in my database and $_POST['password'] it's never the same. The hashPassword give me a new one every time. I really don't know what to do. With md5 it's pretty simple and quick. Bcrypt ... another story.

Comment: You use password_hash for creating another password hash and password_verify to check if the entered password matches with the stored hash. So you use `password_verify($_POST['password'], $storedHash);`

Comment: @Rabah - It's really not that big of a difference. Remove the "password" from your query (just search for the login). If you get a result, just compare the password with `password_verify()` to see if the credentials match. You basically just move the password check from the query to the code after instead.

Comment: @Rabah - Getting different hashes for the same password is on purpose, it is because of salting and is a **must** for secure password hashes.